# SQL filter by row level

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query that filters data based on a certain criteria. The table that I am looking at has invoice orderline data. For example, Invoice #1 is shown multiple times depending on all of the orderlines (tax, discount, base price, etc). So I wan't to show all invoices in which an invoice has a discount applied to it, but I still want to see all of the other orderline rows. If I do a where statement for all rows that contain discount it segregates everything else. So how would i write a query that displays ALL of the orderline rows of the invoice if there is a discount applied to it?

Comment: Would it be some sort of modified if statement

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE InvoiceID IN ( SELECT InvoiceID FROM MyTable WHERE Discount = True )
```

This first gets all the invoices that have a discount, finds the ID field, and uses that to return all the lines of all invoices with a discount.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using sub-queries, for example:

```
select *
from Invoice inv
where id IN (select id from Invoice where discount > 0 )
```

the sub-query will search for all ids with discounts in it, and the query will show all entries for the ids on that sub-query